# Move/Change boot file system

Tags: arm, u-boot

I have a webcam Sunluxy 720p and I need to adapt the configuration to my needs.
The `/` filesystem is read-only.
I have access to `u-boot` via UART/USB cable.
I can also connect via telnet as root.

`printenv` in `u-boot`:

```
bootfile="uImage"
bootargs=mem=36M console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=squashfs rw init=/sbin/init mtdparts=hi_sfc:1024k(boot),3072k(kernel),7168k(rootfs),5120k(system)
bootcmd=sf probe 0;sf read 0x82000000 0x100000 0x300000;bootm 0x82000000;
```

---

```
uname -r

Linux (none) 3.0.8 #30 Tue May 27 21:58:10 CST 2014 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

---

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo

Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 217.08
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : hi3518
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

---

This command cannot find the file.

```
find / -name uImage
```

---

I started by making a backup (`/mnt/sda0` automatically mounted if I insert a micro SD).

```
dd if=/dev/mtdblock0 of=/mnt/sda0/mtdblock0-sunluxy.img bs=65536
dd if=/dev/mtdblock1 of=/mnt/sda0/mtdblock1-sunluxy.img bs=65536
dd if=/dev/mtdblock2 of=/mnt/sda0/mtdblock2-sunluxy.img bs=65536
dd if=/dev/mtdblock3 of=/mnt/sda0/mtdblock3-sunluxy.img bs=65536
```

---

I compared (`diff`) with `dd if=/dev/mtdX` and `dd if=/dev/mtdXro`. There is no difference.

---

With the `file` command (on my Archlinux PC) I have this information:

```
mtdblock0-sunluxy.img: data
mtdblock1-sunluxy.img: u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-3.0.8, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel Image (Not compressed), 2134796 bytes, Tue May 27 13:58:15 2014, Load Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, Header CRC: 0x62D4DC94, Data CRC: 0x6666C9A6
mtdblock2-sunluxy.img: Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, 6336622 bytes, 513 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Wed Jun  4 11:12:34 2014
mtdblock3-sunluxy.img: Linux jffs2 filesystem data little endian
```

---

On webcam, `mtdblock3` is mounted to `/system`.

I believe it is possible to put the contents of `mtdblock2` and `mtdblock3` on micro SD without touching the flash memory partitions, but I do not know how.